# protect and validate multiple range with multiple conditions and validations

Tags: google-apps-script

The below code is working, but, taking long time to execute

```
var j=0;
for(var j=0;j<k;j++)
{
    var cell = billsheet.getRange('M'+(billlastrow+(j+1)));
    var range = contractorsheet.getRange(vrangearray[j][0]);
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
    var prange = billsheet.getRange('E'+(billlastrow+j+1)+':P'+(billlastrow+j+1));
    var protection = prange.protect();
    //var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();//don't use this line
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    protection.addEditor(vrangearray[j][1]);  
    //Logger.log(j);
} // end for k
```

I modified the code as below

```
var depts = packagesheet.getRange('B1:AJ5').getValues();
var billarray=[];
var crangearray=[];
var prangearray=[];
var vrangearray=[];
var erangearray=[];


var j=0;
var k=0
for(var j=0;j<=34;j++)
{
  if (depts[0][j]=="" || laborvalues[0][(j+1)]=="-") {} else {
    k++
    if (depts[0][j].substring(0,5)=="Extra") {var extra=1} else {var extra=0};
    //                         ID              Lot    ID_Lot                       Customer             Panel          Section      Dept       Qty    Remark Start  COMPLETED,   End Contractor    Rate                  Rate2                 Bill     Supervisor   Fed    Colour    Extra
    billarray.push([ordervalues[0][0], lotno, ordervalues[0][0]+'/'+lotno, ordervalues[0][1], ordervalues[0][2],depts[0][j],depts[1][j],lotqty , "",    today,   "",        "",   ""         ,laborvalues[0][j+1] , laborvalues[0][j+1]  , ""   ,  depts[4][j], today,    color, extra]);    //'=VLOOKUP($C'+(billlastrow+1)+',Completed!$C:J,8,0)'
    crangearray.push([ 'M'+(billlastrow+k+1) ]  ); //contractor drop down cell
    prangearray.push([ 'E'+(billlastrow+k+1)+':P'+(billlastrow+k+1)]); //range to be protected
    vrangearray.push([ "Contractor!"+depts[2][j] ]); //valid contractor list
    erangearray.push([ depts[3][j] ]); //valid emails for giving editing rights
  }//if section=""
} // end for 34
//insert full bill at once
billsheet.getRange("A"+(billlastrow+1)+":T"+(billlastrow+(billarray.length))).setValues(billarray);
//set drop down for contractors
var destinationRange = billsheet.getRange(crangearray);
var sourceRange = contractorsheet.getRange(vrangearray);
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange).build();
var rules = destinationRange.getDataValidations();
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < rules[i].length; j++) {
     rules[i][j] = rule;
   }
}
destinationRange.setDataValidations(rules);
//set protection for different production people
var prange = billsheet.getRange(prangearray);
var protection = prange.protect();
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
protection.addEditor(erangearray);
```

It is throwing error at the below line :

```
var destinationRange = billsheet.getRange(crangearray);
```

I made copy of the spreadsheet :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bdO6IdEcIxkCwlW2o-93jpy7BZYb8nrFDE00u-VzQ4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas how to protect and set validation to a range with different rules for different rows.

Comment: "It is throwing error" - what's the error you're getting?

Comment: not a valid range

Answer (score 0):

The method  `Range.setDataValidation(rule)` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation must indeed be applied to a range, but there is no reason why you cannot define a single row as a range. The problem in your code is a different one - the implementation of the range definition. A range must be defined according to the A1 notation.

If you log your `crangearray` variable, you will realize that

```
Logger.log(crangearray);
```

Has the output

```
[[M152], [M153], [M154], [M155], [M156], [M157], [M158], [M159], [M160], [M161], [M162], [M163], [M164], [M165], [M166], [M167], [M168], [M169], [M170], [M171], [M172], [M173], [M174], [M175], [M176], [M177], [M178], [M179]]
```

This is not a valid argument for `getRange()` and thus, gives you an error in

```
var destinationRange = billsheet.getRange(crangearray);
```

You should change your code and assign crangearray the value `“M152:M179”` (do not forget the double quotes!) to make your function work.

Comment: I want the validation rule on M152 - one rule, then on M153 another rule etc. etc.      Is it possible to set the validation on multiple ranges with a single command?

Comment: Is it possible to getRange(["M152:m152","m153:m153".....]  and then set a validation rule (different rule for different ranges - sequentially)?

Comment: Then you have to declare each cell for which you want to apply a different validation rule as a different range, 
 and you can declare var destinationRange=[]; as an array that contains different ranges (cells) and loop through:  for(var j=0;j<=34;j++)
{crangearray=([ 'M'+(billlastrow+k+1) ]  ); destinationRange[i] = billsheet.getRange(crangearray);} and then assign a different rule to each array entry fo destinationRange